# Scripts don't enqueue after removing plugin

Tags: plugins, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, scripts, uninstallation

Using the Ultimate Member plugin. My custom scripts are loading in my child-theme as follows:

```
function some_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('my-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-s.js', array(), '', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'some_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

I'm trying to remove this plugin, but after deactivating it, my custom scripts stop loading (not CSS, just JS files). Been Googling for a while and can't seem to find an answer. Any idea?

Comment: Are they not enqueueing, or are they not _working_. It's an important difference. If you inspect the HTML of the page do you see script tags for your scripts? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Aren't enqueuing, they aren't shown at all in the source . code